# What does it means: `cgroup_disable=memory` in my `dmesg`?

Tags: 12.04, virtualization, dmesg, optimization

My `dmesg` command give me that result in particular:

```
[0.000000] please try 'cgroup_disable=memory' option if you don't want memory cgroups
```

What does it meanings and how to know what I want around my 'memory cgroups' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) (control groups) are used mainly by [LXC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Containers) (LinuX Containers) and its "memory cgroup" is for process group memory restriction. Unless you need this stuff it's better to disable this feature, since otherwise it consumes a part of RAM for its internal structures and [CPU can be affected as well](http://lwn.net/Articles/516533/).